# Run tcl from batch passing a path as a variable

Tags: batch-file, variables, tcl

I am very new to this so please keep any answer to the simplest form.

I am trying to set a process with a batch file. This process will call a tcl that is looking for some files and then returns to finish. It looks like:

> Batch --> Call tcl --> return to batch

In my batch file I have:

Set MyPath = `C:\the path that files are in\`
And then I am calling the tcl which is in `$MyPath$\MyTcl.tcl`

That works ok up to here. But then in the tcl there are some processes that are looking for files in the same path (MyPath) and I am not sure how to use that same variable (pass the variable).

Any help?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: wrong syntax for batch: `set "MyPath=C:\the path that files are in\"` and `call %MyPath%\MyTcsl.tcl`

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your Tcl process to somehow know about that path.

This can be done either implicitly or explicitly.

The way to do that implicitly is to change the working directory
into that "C:\the path that files are in" — the spawned Tcl interpreter
process will inherit it as its so-called "current working directory",
and it could be queried in the Tcl code it runs by means of
executing the [`[pwd]` command](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/pwd.htm)
(or just referencing the files using relative paths since such paths
gets resolved by the OS as rooted in the current working directory
of the process.

The explicit ways to do that are many; you can:

- "Export" the variable in your batch script and read it back
  in your Tcl code — from the so-called
  ["process environment block"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Environment_Block).

  IIRC, batch scripts on Windows export all varibles created via `set`
  by default already, so in your Tcl script you could access that
  value by reading the `::env(MyPath)` variable.
  [Here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/tclvars.htm#M5) is how that works.
- Pass it as a command-line argument to your script.

  In order to do that, your script has to be modified to actually
  read its command-line arguments.

  This is done by reading the `::argc` (number of command-line arguments)
  and `::argv` (the values of these arguments) global variables.
  [Here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/tclvars.htm#M45) is how that works.
- There exist more involved ways to communicate any data to a subprocess
  (such as via a temporary file or via the process's standard input stream)
  but they are too complicated for such a simple case, so let's not explore
  this direction for now.

Answer (score 1):

```
set myPath [file dirname [info script]]
```

https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/info.htm
https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm